# Can I change the server root of my Prepros live preview?

Tags: prepros

I am building a site with Prepros using pug and have a directory structure similar to this:

```
/my-project
  +-dist
  | index.html
  | |
  | +-images
  |   logo.png
  |
  +-pug
    index.pug
```

I want to use absolute links in my final build. For example `<img src="/images/logo.png">`

However live preview sets to root directory one level above my /dist directory so absolute links are broken. I **don't** want my live preview to default to this view:

[image: Screen shot of default live preview.]

**Is there a way to make Prepros live preview assume my /dist folder is the webroot rather than /my-project?**

Comment: I can do this in VS Code's Live Server extension by editing the `liveServer.settings.root` setting. That's exactly what I want to do here in Prepros.